# how to paste part of VBA array to excel range

Tags: excel, vba

Is it somehow possible to past part of an vba array to an excel range?

I need to do something like this:

```
dim testday() as Variant
testday = Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").Value
Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").Value = ""
Sheets("Interface").Range("B4:E4") = testday(3, 4, 5, 6).Value
```

but this doesn't work... is there a way to fix this? Thx!

Comment: I prefer `Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").ClearContents`

Comment: Yeah, I usually do, but I have them conditional formatted and I want to keep that, but thx!

Comment: `ClearContents` doesn't remove the conditional formatting.

Comment: hmm ok so that is different than .clear? thx for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- Use a loop to copy the values you need to a new array, and write that to your range. If you're going to do this often, you can write a reusable function that does this. Or,
- Read only what you need from your `"raw"` sheet, and write that to your range, as illustrated below. This is probably the simplest solution in your particular case.

```
Dim testday() As Variant
testday = Sheets("raw").Range("G745:J745").Value ' only read what you need
Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").ClearContents
Sheets("Interface").Range("B4:E4") = testday(3, 4, 5, 6).Value
```

Comment: yeah thx, but I need testday(7,8,9,10) to C4:E4 etc. so first method would be better

Answer (score 2):

You can ***Slice*** the `Array` using `Index` function

```
Sub Slicer()
 Dim testday() As Variant
 testday = Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").Value
 Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").Value = ""
 Sheets("Interface").Range("B4:E4")= Application.Index(testday, 1, Array(3, 4, 5, 6))
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a cool approach and it beats mine on simplicity (+1). Instead of `Array(3,4,5)` I would use `Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & lStartIndex & ":" & lFinishIndex & "))")`, which makes a one-dimensional array of numbers starting with `lStartIndex` all the way to `lFinishIndex`, and can be used to allocate an arbitrary long (contiguous) array dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand your use of Index. The last value should be a column number, but you have an array instead? How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

If the array you want to copy is one-dimensional, and you need to copy contiguous cells you can use the [CopyMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366535(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)


Sub test()
  Dim vArr(), vArr2()
  Dim lCnt As Long
  Dim lStartIndex As Long, lFinishIndex As Long, lLength As Long


  With Application
    vArr = .Transpose(.Transpose(Range("A1:R1").Value2))
  End With

  lStartIndex = 3
  lFinishIndex = 6
  lLength = lFinishIndex - lStartIndex + 1

  ReDim vArr2(1 To lLength)

  CopyMemory vArr2(1), vArr(lStartIndex), lLength * 16

  For lCnt = LBound(vArr2) To UBound(vArr2)
    Debug.Print vArr2(lCnt)
  Next lCnt

  Range("A2").Resize(1, UBound(vArr2)).Value2 = vArr2

End Sub
```

Tested with first row being

```
67.2    9   57.2    boo 52  64  76  39  48  50  28  54  96  29  98  25  68  19
```

returns

```
57.2    boo 52  64
```

on the second row.
So your snippet would change as

```
dim testday(), testday2()
With Application  ' Value2 is faster than Value
  testday = .Transpose(.Transpose(Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").Value2))
End With
Sheets("raw").Range("E745:BN745").ClearContents   ' Good suggestion by JFC
CopyMemory testday2(1), testday(3), 4 * 16        ' Variant = 16 Bytes
Sheets("Interface").Range("B4:E4").Value2 = testday2  ' I would do Resize instead
```

I hope this helps!